# Equivalent of as: :json when performing a call in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I'm unfamiliar with this syntax `as: :json`

I can convert the following:

```
session.put-= '/animals', params: data, headers:{"test-auth": token_key}
```

to the following function: (where session represents open_session)

```
session.put(route, params:data, headers:{"test-auth": token_key})
```

However, how would I set the following that uses `as: :json`

```
 session.put '/animals', params: data, as: :json, headers:{"test-auth": token_key}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  session.put(route, params: data, as: :json, headers: {..})
```

The signature of the method is probably something along the lines of:

```
def put(route, params = {params: {}, as: 'default', headers: {}})
... block of coode
end
```

The colon after `as:` is saying that as is a key in a hash. `:json` is just a ruby symbol.